# Code generating error and needs improvement

Tags: python

I currently have this code, but when I run it I get the error:

> NameError: global name 'array_of_lines_strings' is not defined

also, the commented out code represents what I want to do next which is to not only run the search function on 1 file but on all files within the folder using glob, how do I do this and fix my error?

```
import re
AS = re.compile('approve stipulation between', re.IGNORECASE) 
OG = re.compile('Order Granting', re.IGNORECASE)
from glob import glob
import pandas as pd
import os

with open(r'C:\Users\234234234234\Desktop\termlist.txt') as f:
    termlist = f.readlines()
termlist = [x.strip().lower().split(' ') for x in termlist]


def keep(line):
    match = AS.findall(line)
    if (len(match) > 0):
        return True

    match = OG.findall(line)
    if (len(match) > 0):
        return True

    return False


def search(file_name):
    with open(file_name, 'r') as f:
        termlist = f.readlines()
    termlist = [x.strip().lower().split(' ') for x in termlist]
    for line_number in range(1, len(array_of_lines_strings)):
        for search_term in term_list:
            if search_term in list(set(lines_to_scan)):
                found_lines_list.append([line_number -1, line_number])    

if __name__ == '__main__':
    directoryPath = r'C:\Users\234234234234\Desktop\eric__pdf'
    file_list = glob("C:\\Users\\234234234234\Desktop\\eric_pdf\\*.txt")
    os.chdir(directoryPath)
    folder_list=os.listdir(directoryPath)
    search('C:\\Users\\234234234234\\Desktop\\eric_pdf\\eric.txt')    

'''
    results = []
for file in file_list:    
    with open(file) as f:
        for line in f:
            if (keep(line)):
                results.append(line)
df = pd.DataFrame({'results': results})
df.to_csv('results.txt') 
'''
```

Comment: Where are you defining `array_of_lines_strings`?

Answer (score 0):

In your `search` method, you include the line:

```
for line_number in range(1, len(array_of_lines_strings)):
```

but your variable `array_of_lines_strings` has never been defined, so you can't ask for the length of a variable that does not yet exist.

Did you mean for the prior line in that method to be

```
array_of_lines_strings = [x.strip().lower().split(' ') for x in termlist]
```

(instead of `termlist =` . . . )?

I also caution that you have two different variables that look very alike: `termlist` and `term_list`. If you intended them to be the same, pick one or the other. If you intended the variables to mean different things, you will be better off giving them more descriptive names so you don't end up confusing yourself later.